# Composer does not install package laravel-ide-helper

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

I am trying to install `laravel-ide-helper` with next command:

```sh
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

Then I see next output:

```sh
Using version ^2.9 for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

But in `vendor` directory there is no `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` folder, so I can not run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` due to error `There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.`

Am I doing something wrong? Why package does not install?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried clean cache, delete `vendor`, delete `.lock` file - no result.

Comment: @NicoHaase The last idea is to update composer inside docker, doing it right now

Comment: What do you mean by "inside docker"? Can you share more details about this by editing your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase I replaced composer installation with `RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`, so `composer` was upgraded to `2.0.9` and problem was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, updating composer to version `2.0.9` (latest version for January 27, 2021) solves the problem.